# How to submit input field in upload form as well as for each individual file upload

Tags: file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp's fileupload plugin to implement multiple file uploads.

My sample form:

```
    <form id="fileupload" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/main/upload_img'; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="foldername">
</form>
```

I have also added additional text input in the upload template:

```
<input type="text" name="tags[]">
```

In order to send the tags value to the server, I have to use formData option; rendering my foldername input value null. How do I send both input value to the server?

Comment: Did you happen to get this figured out? If so, could you share your code as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's been covered here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data

What you can do is to use JQuery's serializeArray method, which creates a JavaScript array of objects:

```
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Nikkster. That's where I'm a bit lost. Here is my sample code:

`$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
  var tags = $("input[name^=tags]");
  var inputs = data.context.find(tags);
  data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
 });
`

Where should I put the var formData code?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. According to your sample code, you're already ready to go. All the form data should be sent to the server. Are you having any errors in your web browser console? You can also validate to see if any client-side errors occur by printing to the console - console.log("message"), as I'm not able to test your code at the moment I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. there's no error in the web console. Using the above code will only send the input tags values (as per documented in the blueimp wiki). I can't seem to fetch the input foldername value.

Comment: Oh sorry. You're right, now you're only sending the tags inputs. Try the following code:             $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
                var formData = $('form');
                var inputs = data.context.find(formData);
                data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
            });

Comment: Or you can try multiple selector, e.g. input[name=tags] and input[name=foldername] or just go with :input.